# Бот для telegram c библиотекой COVID19Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть такой код для бота в телеграм который берет инфу о коронавирусе и выводит ее пользователя, но вот незадача при вводе определенной странны он выдает ошибку:

> ```
> \final_message = f"<u>Данные по США:</u>\n<b>Заболевших: </b>{location['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Смертей: </b>{location['deaths']:,}"\
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str\
> ```

как это можно решить?

```py
import telebot
import COVID19Py

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()
bot = telebot.TeleBot("APi ключ")


@bot.message_handler(commands= ['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет!, меня зовут кабот, я могу показать статистку о коронавирусе!')

@bot.message_handler(commands= ['help'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Комнады которые я умею')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def goga(message):
    final_message = ""
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()
    if get_message_bot == "сша":
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")
        final_message = f"<u>Данные по США:</u>\n<b>Заболевших: </b>{location['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Смертей: </b>{location['deaths']:,}"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message)
```

Comment: Очевидно, не допускать того, чтобы индексом списка была строка.

Comment: `location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")` -> `location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")[0]`. Всё потому-что `getLocationByCountryCode` всегда возвращает [список мест](https://github.com/Kamaropoulos/COVID19Py/blob/c8d8d2a69d64c3a6e59e6e2fa5901522649516fb/COVID19Py/covid19.py#L130). По уму, надо ещё проверить что в списке что-то есть.